# generating suppressions for memory leaks

Tags: valgrind, error-suppression

I want suppress Valgrind's reporting of some "definitely lost" memory by the library I'm using. I have tried `valgrind --gen-suppressions=yes ./a` but it only prompts for *errors* such as "conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value".

Is there a way to generate suppressions for straight-up memory leaks? If not, is it difficult to write them by hand? Valgrind's manpage seems to discourage it, at least for errors.

Answer (score 7):

Run valgrind with the `--gen-suppressions=all` and `--log-file=memcheck.log` options, and manually copy/paste the logged suppressions into the suppression file.

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --gen-suppressions=all --log-file=memcheck.log ./a
```

If you find the output is mixed with the application output then redirect valigrind output to separate file descriptor: `--log-fd=9 9>>memcheck.log`

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --gen-suppressions=all --log-fd=9 ./a  9>>memcheck.log
```

Comment: The trick to separate valgrind's output from the application is super useful, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

To be prompted for leaks that aren't generating errors, you have to run

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --gen-suppressions=yes ./a
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a page on how you can generate such a file based on your errors https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto

It's not perfect, but you can start from it

Answer (score -2):

You can [write a suppression file](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.suppfiles) of your own (but it doesn't seem obvious) :

```
--suppressions=<filename> [default: $PREFIX/lib/valgrind/default.supp]
```

If the question was to disable an entire library, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4226706/1715716).

Valgrind's [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/valgrind).

Comment: The `--suppressions` option is required to read suppression file, not write