# Make a valgrind error suppression generic for an object library, with wildcards

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

Using valgrind in the context of a C++ project, I have been trying to [suppress](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) memory leak information coming from third party libraries. I would generate the specific suppression file entry running valgrind with `--gen-suppressions=all` and obtain for example:

```
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: reachable
   fun:malloc
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.515.105.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.515.105.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.515.105.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.515.105.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.515.105.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.515.105.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.515.105.01
   obj:/usr/local/cuda-11.6/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.6.55
   obj:/usr/local/cuda-11.6/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.6.55
   obj:/usr/local/cuda-11.6/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.6.55
   obj:/usr/local/cuda-11.6/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.6.55
}
```

Now I would like to generalize that rule so that it suppresses any warning coming from any library called `*libcuda*`. I tried different things, like:

```
{
   cuda
   memcheck:Leak
   ...
   obj:*libcuda*
   ...
}
```

or

```
{
   cuda
   memcheck:Leak
   obj:*libcuda*
}
```

or (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4226706/2436175))

```
{
   cuda
   memcheck:Leak
   fun:*alloc
   ...
   obj:*libcuda*
   ...
}
```

None of this worked, so even if the suppression file is read by valgrind with no complaint, none of my libcuda originated messages get suppressed.
Is there a way to make Valgrind accept this kind of generic suppression commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you have mispelled `Memcheck` with lowercase `m`.

The following will work:

```
{
   cuda
   Memcheck:Leak
   ...
   obj:*libcuda*
}
```

The last frame wildcard `...` you had put is not necessary.